# Is it possible to create functions with specific addresses?

Tags: solidity

I want to do functions involving a few specific addresses. They are defined as such at the top of the contract :

```
 address lockaddress = 0x36667BCBBE6574520fba783410beB6C0AfDE5043; //replace with real lockaddress 
address companyaddress = 0x49CcAF0ca6afd79Be35b908b34431b553cF21e9b; //replace with real companyaddress 
address team1 = 0xdE6B5637C4533a50a9c38D97CDCBDEe129fd966D; //replace with jeffs address or whoever deploys the contract
```

They are then called in this function.

```
function UnlockLocked () public {
 if (LockTime1 + 730 days <= now) { 
   if (address(msg.sender) == team1) {
       _balances(address(lockaddress)) = 
       _balances(address(lockaddress)).sub(_balances(address(lockaddress)));
       _balances(address(team1)) = _balances(address(team1)).add(45000000000000000000000000);
       emit Transfer (address(lockaddress), team1, 45000000000000000000000000);
   }
   else {

   }
  } 
  else {

  }
}
```

The error seems to revolve around _balances, which is defined as such

```
  mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
```

I get errors such as :

```
TypeError: Type is not callable
TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.
```

Is it actually possible to create functions using specific set addresses? If so, how can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined `_balances` as follows:

```
mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
```

then you should use this variable as `_balances[theAddress]` not with parenthesis.

You can also define a function to get the balance of an account, but you should use `_balances` in this function:

```
function getBalance(address x) private view returns(uint) {
  return _balances[x];
}
```